# Formatar data no carregamento da página

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Olá queria formatar a data do meu formulário no carregamento da página, porque a data está vindo do banco de dados no formato internacional (yyyy-mm-dd).

Fiz essa função para formatar minha data, porém eu tenho 2 formulários na mesma página e ambos tem inputs do mesmo nome. Meu input  está no formato de texto.

```
function formataData(ele){
    var value = $(ele).val();
    var d = undefined;
    if(value.search('-') > -1){
        d = $(ele).val().split('-');
        console.log(d);
    } else if($(ele).val().search('/') > -1) {
        d = $(ele).val().split('/');
        console.log(d);
    }

    if(d !== undefined){
        if(d[0].length > 3){
            $(ele).val(d[2]+'/'+d[1]+'/'+d[0]);
        }else {
            $(ele).val(d[2]+'-'+d[1]+'-'+d[0]);         
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Resumindo o que eu queria**

-A página carrega assim:

```
<input type="text" name="vencimento" value="yyyy-mm-dd" class="form-control">
```

-Queria chamar minha função javascript/JQuery no carregamento da página para ficar assim:

```
<input type="text" name="vencimento" value="dd-mm-yyyy" class="form-control">
```

Usei $(document).ready(function(){}); mas ficou cambiarra demais :/ queria reaproveitar essa função em outros códigos! Obrigado pela atenção.

**Obs: tinha esquecido, quero chamar esta função para todos os campos de data no carregamento da página também**

Comment: Porque não mudas a query na base de dados para te dar o que queres de inicio?

Comment: Seria melhor mesmo. Mas como eu chamaria uma função JS no load da página? Sem ter que fazer gambiarra. @Sergio

Comment: e como você traz a data do banco?

Comment: Qual linguagem da sua página?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Estou usando PHP, Js/JQuery, Mysql

Comment: porque não faz no php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você não puder mudar como os dados vêm da base, use o seguinte:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   ajeita();

});
```

Vai ajeitar o formato em todos os campos com a classe `form-control`

> Teste no snippet abaixo:

```js
function ajeita() {  
    $('input.form-control').each(function () {
        var data = $(this).val().split('-').reverse();
        $(this).val(data.join('-'))
    });  
};

//opção sem jQuery
const ajeita2 = () => {
  document
  .querySelectorAll('.form-control')
  .forEach(el => el.value = el.value.split('-').reverse().join('-'))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="1990-10-25" class="form-control" /><br />
<input type="text" value="1991-11-16" class="form-control" /><br />
<input type="text" value="1980-08-25" class="form-control" /><br />
<input type="text" value="2010-05-04" class="form-control" /><br />


<input type="button" value="testar" onclick="ajeita();" />
<input type="button" value="testar (sem jQuery)" onclick="ajeita2();" />
```

Comment: Editei porque eu tinha usado "yyyy/mm/dd" em vez de "yyyy-mm-dd"

Comment: Tranquilo, obrigado, essa função each é bem útil, sabia que existia mas não o que fazia. @LeonKlaj

Answer (score 1):

```
$dataBanco1="2016-01-21"; // pra servir de exemplo
$dataBanco2="2016-01-23"; // pra servir de exemplo
$data1 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dataBanco1));
$data2 = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dataBanco2));
<input type="text" name="vencimento" value="<?php echo $data1 ?> " class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="vencimento" value="<?php echo $data2 ?> " class="form-control">
```

Comment: Sim, sim, eu tinha entendido @LeoCaracciolo porém nem todos campos vem do Banco de dados, queria fazer isso também, para quando o usuário fosse criar um dado, entende? Mas mesmo assim obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

*Já venho tarde talvez com a minha resposta..., mas:*

Se queres fazer isso no browser e **todas** as datas estão em formato `yyyy-mm-dd` podes fazer assim:

```
$('input.form-control').each(function(){
    this.value = this.value.split('-').reverse().join('-');
});
```

Se podes mudar isso no servidor, no SQL, podes fazer:

```
DATE_FORMAT(coluna_data, "%d-%m-%Y") AS coluna_data
```

Se podes mudar isso no servidor, no PHP, podes fazer:

```
$data = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($dataOriginal));
echo '<input type="text" name="vencimento" value="'.$data.'" class="form-control">';
```

Comment: Bacana, mas como seria minha query no SQL? select DATE_FORMAT(coluna_data, "%d-%m-%Y") from relatorios. ?

Comment: @MarceloRafael poderia ser `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(coluna_data, "%d-%m-%Y") AS coluna_data FROM relatorios;`.

Comment: posso trocar "$d-%m-%Y" por: "$d/%m/%Y" ? Por barras " / ".

Comment: @MarceloRafael sim podes.